# How Objective-C support Java BigDecimal via Hessian?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, bigdecimal, hessian

Server has a Java Bean, it has a instance variable type `BigDecimal`, but Objective-C cannot map it! I have tried `NSNumber`, but doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this once may be it is usefull

```
    NSDecimalNumber *a = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"9999999999999999999999999999999999.99999999999"];
    NSDecimalNumber *b;
    NSDecimalNumber *half = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"999999999.9999999999"];
    b = [half decimalNumberByAdding:a]; 
    NSLog(@"The subtration :%@",b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDecimalNumber instead of NSNumber.

Here is the code to convert a string to a NSDecimal

```
-(NSDecimal) getDecimalFromString:(NSString*)representationString {
    NSDecimal result;
    NSScanner *theScanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:representationString];
    [theScanner setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [theScanner scanDecimal:&result];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I want to map remote Java bean with Objective-C protocols, the Java data type `long` is mapped with type `long` in Objective-C, but Xcode builds error and shows "Unknown type l for property long1 in protocol Test" :( What's the map list about data type translation?

Comment: is this what you need? http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/primitives.html